# Opencv c++ linemod- problems loading templates

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm attempting to implement the linemod algorithm for textureless object recognition from OpenCV, but I'm having some trouble adding the templates (training images to match- effectively) to the detector.

There appear to be a number of ways to instantiate the main detector class:

```
linemod::Detector detector; //empty constructor

linemod::Detector detector (Modalities, T_pyramid); //regular constructor

Ptr<linemod::Detector> detector
detector= linemod::getDefaultLINEMOD //Setting a pointer to a default version
```

Then add the template:

```
int templ_id = detector.addTemplate(sources,class_id,mask)
int templ_id = detector->addTemplate(sources,class_id,mask)
```

My issue is that the template adding fails UNLESS I use the empty constructor version, in which case it seems to work fine. Unfortunately I'm not really sure how I'd use the empty constructor, it seems to be built around loading from file. The default version, or otherwise the one I constructed are what I want to work with.

Weird point but attempting to add the template will add a class_ID to the detector even if the template loading fails- this returns -1 on templ_id and calls of numTemplates are 0.. but numClasses starts 0 and goes up to 1 even if the template fails to add.

I've tried fiddling with this endlessly but can't seem to get it working. I'm new to c++ so it's possible I'm missing some obvious context or easy solution.

This is the reference for the detector class and all the other linemod classes, functions etc:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d07/classcv_1_1linemod_1_1Detector.html

and the full code:

```
//LINEMOD LOAD TEMPLATE TO DETECTOR CLASS

/*
Loosely based on http://answers.opencv.org/question/17424/opencv-cvlinemod-throwing-runtime-errors/
Code displays:
-Appropriate libraries
-How to instantiate the detector class from opencv
-How to load a template from file to the detector
Next stage is to load full set for one or many objects, or to test matching capability.
PW: 02/07/18
*/

#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/rgbd.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

string train_path = "/home/pete/work/data/train/15/rgb/0500.png";
string test_path = "/home/pete/work/data/test/";
string test_image = "/home/pete/work/pxw762/linemod/test_image.jpeg";     

int main() 
{

//Load in image(s) 
Mat rgb;
Mat depth;
rgb = imread("/home/pete/work/data/train/15/rgb/0500.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
depth = imread("/home/pete/work/data/train/15/depth/0500.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
vector<Mat> sources; 
sources.push_back(rgb);
sources.push_back(depth); //Put images into source vector

//Create mask
Mat gray, mask;
cvtColor(rgb,gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(gray,mask,0,1,THRESH_BINARY);
mask.convertTo(mask, CV_8U);

//Add a template
cv::Ptr<cv::linemod::Detector> detector;
detector=linemod::getDefaultLINEMOD();

string class_id = "15";
int templ_ID = detector->addTemplate(sources, class_id, mask); //Add a template to the detector
cout<<templ_ID<<endl;

//Testing section
string num_classes= to_string(detector->numClasses());
string num_templates= to_string(detector->numTemplates());
cout<<"Number of classes: "<<num_classes<<endl;
cout<<"Number of Templates: "<<num_templates<<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas of what might be going wrong here?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I had a similar issue and in my case the mask was faulty. Interestingly, it worked if I just declared `Mat mask` and passed that to the addTemplate function. You could try that, but actually I think yours is looking well. Maybe you could try with only using the ColorGradient modality first, to further isolate the problem?

Comment: Thanks man, I got past this a while back. There were actually two separate issues here that were causing issues and both had to be solved concurrently for it to work. One was the size, as the algorithm is optimised for 800x600 images (I think) and fails to generate any matches with much different sizing... and the second, I can't actually remember!